# How to find duplicates in array of strings in D?

Tags: arrays, d, duplicates

I have got array if strings that have some duplicates. What is the best way to find all them?

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Sort the array. Then, duplicate strings will follow each other:

   ```
   arr.sort();
   foreach (i; 0..arr.length-1)
       if (arr[i] == arr[i-1])
           ....
   ```

   Also see [`std.algorithm.uniq`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#.uniq).
2. Use an associative array (hashmap):

   ```
   bool[string] seen;
   foreach (s; arr)
       if (s !in seen)
           seen[s] = true;
       else
           ...
   ```